# Which model would fit the original data given these ACF and PACF plots?

Tags: stochastic-processes, time-series

Given the following plots, I am confused as to which model would fit the best. Also, I am not sure how to incorporate the first difference ACF/PACF plots in the answer.

You can find the plots [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZS0a.jpg)

Comment: My initial guess would be an $\operatorname{AR}(1)$ process on the differences. I am unsure what your question is. Do you need help with understanding the acf and partial acf? Are you asking how one can use the acf and partial acf plots to specify a model?

Comment: In R you can get differences by e.g. `diff(data)`.